# Browsers opens only https sites

Tags: macos, mac, firewall

I have OS X Mavericks on my Mac and 3 browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome). 
When I try to open any site I see only "connecting..", but when I try https sites it works fine!
Ping and traceroute shows normal information.
Internet works over Wi-Fi. (My iPad works fine and opens any address).

I have tried to restatart mDNSResponder and turn off Firewall. But my problem still persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you "telnet hostname 80" ?  Ping and traceroute use different ports than http's default.  So, it is a good way to check the settings.

Comment: `$ telnet google.com 80
Trying 188.43.69.98...`
That's all..

Comment: Something is blocking your port 80; either your computer's firewall or a router further upstream. Do you connect the Ethernet directly to the same router that supplies the wifi signal?

Comment: First troubleshoot the root of the problem. Check your Mac's DNS settings in Network Preferences. Check to see if your router is filtering port 80. Check if your ISP is having issues. There are many places you could look to detect your problem.

Answer (score 4):

188.43.69.98 is a Russian IP and announced as owned by 'Closed Joint Stock Company TransTeleCom' and not is not an official Google IP.  It tries to disguise itself by falsifying its reverse dns pointer pretending to be 'cache.google.com' but this is a lie.

Chances are very high your system has been hijacked somehow.  Perhaps not your Mac but your internet router could be compromised.  My guess you have an ADSL connection on a TP-Link or D-Link ADSL router which are easy targets.

Log in into your router and check what the DNS servers are set to.

Comment: good pickup on the IP address +1

Comment: Indeed Google's IP ranges are [**totally different.**](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/traceipaddresses/f/google-ip-address.htm)

Comment: 'Closed Joint Stock Company TransTeleCom' is my ISP
And i can find here https://db-ip.com/all/188.43.69 it is real Russian Federation - Trans-telecom. And it this is ok.
And 
`'$ telnet facebook.com 80
Trying 173.252.89.132...`
http://www.ipgeek.net/173.252.89.132.html so it's real facebook

Comment: If this is indeed your ISP, somebody over there messed up big time.  Caching Google would be useless except for the Google logo. Pretending to be an official google.com server in the PTR is probably illegal.